# Why does changing the LargeChange value of a scrollbar in C# break it?

Tags: c#, scrollbar

This doesn't really make sense to me. My scroll bar works perfectly if LargeChange is set to 1 but if I set it to 10 it doesn't scroll all the way. If I set it to 100 I can't scroll even further. SmallChange is set to 1 for all of these examples.

I guess what could be happening maybe is that if LargeChange is 10 and the Maximum is 100, for example and if the Value is 95 then you would not be able to scroll at all but even at that value I cannot do a small change at all. This doesn't make any sense to me. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking but according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.largechange.aspx both values SmallChange and LargeChange are "relative" to the scrollbar maximum...

On what scrollbar are you seeing this ? PictureBox ?

EDIT - as per comment:

IF I understand you correctly you will need to something similar to this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/understandingScrollbars.aspx to make it work...

Another point to keep in mind:

*User interface guidelines suggest that the **SmallChange and LargeChange properties are set relative to the size of the view that the user sees, not to the total size** including the unseen part. For example, if you have a picture box with scroll bars displaying a large image, the SmallChange and LargeChange properties should be set relative to the size of the picture box, not to the size of the image.*

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Just the horizontal and vertical scroll bar control. I am using their values for a translation matrix to display parts of a tiled map.

Comment: Not having much luck =( I read both pages. Is a custom control for VScrollBar and HScrollBar really necessary? I'd like to get it working with the default controls..

Comment: you can but then you will have to choose LargeChange smaller than the visible size of the srollable area as mentioned in the MSDN link.

Comment: I got it working. Basically for all future readers set the scroll bar's maximum to the total size including the unseen part. Then (this part is important) change the LargeChange to the viewable size (minus the scroll bar size if it is part of the container)